# I can't inject bower packages with wiredep and no error?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, wiredep

I am trying to inject bower packages to html
using wiredep, but it's not injected and no error appear

this is my gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('inject', function () {

    var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
    var options = {
        bowerJson: require('./bower.json'), //it will return back that json object 
        directory: './public/lib' //where to look for 
    }
    return gulp.src('./src/views/*.html')
        .pipe(wiredep(options))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/views')); // pipe that back into our views directory
});
```

and this is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Storystrap Template</title>
        <meta name="generator" content="Bootply" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work when we try to inject css files with versions after "bootstrap": "3.3.4"

so I dealt with it by overriding the bower packages that I am trying to inject
in my bower.json file
here is the code:

```
"overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "less/bootstrap.less"
      ]
    },
    "font-awesome": {
      "main": [
        "less/font-awesome.less",
        "css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "scss/font-awesome.scss"
      ]
    }
  }
```

hope that was helpful
thanks.